# Given a function $f:X \to Y$,show that $f^{-1}(Y_1-Y_2)=f^{-1}(Y_1)-f^{-1}(Y_2)$ Where $Y_1,Y_2 \subseteq Y$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Given a function $f:X \to Y$,show that $$f^{-1}(Y_1-Y_2)=f^{-1}(Y_1)-f^{-1}(Y_2)$$

Where $Y_1,Y_2 \subseteq Y$.

$$ x \in f^{-1}(Y_1-Y_2)$$
$$ \iff f(x) \in (Y_1-Y_2)$$
$$ \iff f(x) \in Y_1 \wedge  f(x) \notin Y_2 $$
$$ \iff x\in f^{-1}(Y_1) \wedge  x\notin f^{-1}(Y_2)$$
$$ \iff x\in f^{-1}(Y_1)- f^{-1}(Y_2)$$

Is my proof true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. However, I would explain in more details why $f(x) \notin Y_2$ is equivalent to $x \notin f^{-1}(Y_2)$. The reason is that the domain of $f$ is $X$, because $f$ is a function. This equivalence would no longer be true if $f$ were only a partial function.

Comment: Same remark. If $f$ is only a partial function, this equivalence does not hold: if $x \notin \text{Dom}(f)$, then $f(x)$ is not defined.